# How to compile a pie(position independent executable) lib in rust, and use this lib in another crate?

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, compilation, cross-compiling, arm64

I want to compile a pie lib in rust and use it in another cargo project but I met some compile errors. This is the src/lib.rs code of the pie lib:

```rust
#![feature(restricted_std)]                        

pub fn add(left: usize, right: usize) -> usize {
    left + right
}

pub fn output(i: usize) {
    println!("i:{}", i);
}
```

This is the cargo.toml of this crate:

```ini
[package]                                                               
name = "libtest"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]

[lib]
crate-type = ["lib"]
version = "0.1.0"
```

I compiled this crate with this command: `cargo build --lib --target=aarch64-unknown-none-softfloat -Clink-args="-pie"`. However, it threw an error:

```
warning: unused manifest key: lib.version
   Compiling libtest v0.1.0 (/home/user/libtest)
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `std`
  |
  = note: the `aarch64-unknown-none-softfloat` target may not support the standard library
  = note: `std` is required by `libtest` because it does not declare `#![no_std]`
  = help: consider building the standard library from source with `cargo build -Zbuild-std`

error: cannot find macro `println` in this scope
 --> src/lib.rs:8:5
  |
8 |     println!("i:{}", i);
  |     ^^^^^^^

error[E0635]: unknown feature `restricted_std`
 --> src/lib.rs:1:12
  |
1 | #![feature(restricted_std)]
  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0463, E0635.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0463`
```

I searched this on Internet, and change the compile command to `cargo rustc --target aarch64-unknown-none-softfloat --release -Zbuild-std -- -Clink-args="-pie"`. This time it compiled successfully. I found `libtest/target/aarch64-unknown-none-softfloat/release/liblibtest.rlib` and wanted to use this lib in other crate.

I created a cargo project and this is the main.rs.

```
extern crate libtest;                                                                                                   
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let a = libtest::add(1, 2); 
    println!("finish test {}", a); 
}
```

This is the Cargo.toml:

```
[package]                                                                                                               
name = "pie_test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
libtest = { path = "./liblibtest.rlib" }
```

The directory looks like:

```
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── liblibtest.rlib
├── rust-toolchain.toml
└── src
    └── main.rs
```

According to this [rust doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/crates/using_lib.html), I used this command to compile the target crate: `rustc src/main.rs --target aarch64-unknown-none-softfloat --extern libtest=./liblibtest.rlib`. However, it threw errors.

```
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `std`
  |
  = note: the `aarch64-unknown-none-softfloat` target may not support the standard library
  = note: `std` is required by `<unknown>` because it does not declare `#![no_std]`
  = help: consider building the standard library from source with `cargo build -Zbuild-std`

error[E0463]: can't find crate for `std` which `libtest` depends on
 --> src/main.rs:1:1
  |
1 | extern crate libtest; 
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate
  |
  = note: the `aarch64-unknown-none-softfloat` target may not support the standard library
  = help: consider building the standard library from source with `cargo build -Zbuild-std`

error: cannot find macro `println` in this scope
 --> src/main.rs:5:5
  |
5 |     println!("finish test {}", a);
  |     ^^^^^^^

error: cannot find macro `println` in this scope
 --> src/main.rs:3:5
  |
3 |     println!("Hello, world!");
  |     ^^^^^^^

error: `#[panic_handler]` function required, but not found

error: aborting due to 5 previous errors

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0463`.
```

If I used this command to compile `cargo build --target aarch64-unknown-none-softfloat`, it also threw errors:

```
error: failed to get `libtest` as a dependency of package `pie_test v0.1.0 (/home/user/pie_test)`

Caused by:
  failed to load source for dependency `libtest`

Caused by:
  Unable to update /home/user/pie_test/liblibtest.rlib

Caused by:
  failed to read `/home/user/pie_test/liblibtest.rlib/Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  Not a directory (os error 20)
```

My environment is ubuntu 20.04 x86_64. And the rustc version is `rustc 1.69.0-nightly (13471d3b2 2023-03-02)`.
And this is the output of `rustup component list | grep aarch64` command:

```
...
rust-std-aarch64-unknown-none (installed)
rust-std-aarch64-unknown-none-softfloat (installed)
...
```

I would like to know how I can compile a pie rlib and use it in another rust project for aarch64.

Comment: use "/home/zgctsm/libtest" (or it's relative equivalent) as path in the binaries `Cargo.toml` and just compile the binary with `cargo` and all relevant flags, that'll build the library as well.

Comment: @cafce25 Hi, I change the cargo.toml in pie_test (libtest = { path = "absolute_path_libtest" }), however when I use `cargo rustc --target aarch64-unknown-none-softfloat -Zbuild-std -- -Clink-args="-pie"` to compile, it also threw error: `error: cannot find macro `println` in this scope` and `error[E0463]: can't find crate for `panic_abort``

Comment: I test the doc in this [site](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/crates/using_lib.html). I just add a option 'target'. The full command is `rustc --crate-type=lib --target=aarch64-unknown-none-softfloat rary.rs`. It threw the error `error: cannot find macro 'print' in this scope`,  `error: cannot find macro 'println' in this scope`. I suppose there may be something wrong with `aarch64-unknown-none-softfloat `, but I have checked the `aarch64-unknown-none-softfloat (installed)`